# retrofit library doesn't support all devices versions

Tags: android

`Retrofit` `library` does not support all devices versions.
I use `retrofit 2 version '2.3.0'`, it supports high android versions but does not support low versions.

And when I use `retrofit 2 version '1.9.0'`, it supports low android versions but does not support high versions.

This problem appear when i run app on phone ,it works correctly in some phones and executes 'onFailure' code in some phones.

what is the solution?

Comment: I do not think retrofit is dependent on the android api version. Can you provide the code for what problem are you facing.

Comment: why do you think that `retrofit 2 version '2.3.0',it supports high android versions but does not support low versions`? How do you know that?

Comment: This problem appear when i run app on phone ,it works correctly in some phones and executes 'onFailure' code in some phones.